# Vaadin Flow: How to add Azure Active Directory Login function?

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, vaadin

I want to add Active Directory to my Vaadin Flow Application but I can't find any tutorial for that... Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  What vaadin specifics prevent you from using it?

Comment: If your company has a subscription that includes the SSO kit, you can use that https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/tools/sso

Answer (score 0):

About 10 years ago I used this approach to implement this:

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Ldap{

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Ldap.class);
    @EJB
    private Settings settings;

    public boolean isAutorizated(final String userName, final String password){
        InitialDirContext dirContext = null;
        boolean retval = false;

        final Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, settings.getString("DEFAULT.LdapServerUrl"));
        final String loginName = settings.getString("DEFAULT.Domain") + '\\' + userName;
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, loginName);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        try {
            dirContext = new InitialDirContext(env);
            log.info("Login success for user " + loginName);
            if (dirContext != null) {
                dirContext.close();
            }
            retval = true;
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            log.error("Login failed for user " + loginName);
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

and method call:

```java
...
@EJB
private Ldap ldap;

public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
   if (ldap.isAutorizated(login.getValue(), password.getValue())){
   // do on success
   } else{
   // do on failure
   }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is based on LDAP. As far as I know Azure AD does not support LDAP. The more correct way - IMHO - would be to use Spring Security and then possibly SAML against the Azure AD (if internal app) or OpenID. There are other options as well.