# Vaadin security with LDAP

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, vaadin

i'm really struggling to create an vaadin application with ldap authentication. I went through all tutorials from Vaadin offical about implementing authentication in Vaadin application, but all videos and tutorials include a simple example with InMemoryUserDetailsManager.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0}")
        .groupSearchBase("CN=APP_USER,OU=Groups,OU=Company AD Objects,OU=Admin company")
        .contextSource()
        .url("ldap://localhost:389/DC=com")
        .managerDn("user-admin-app")
        .managerPassword("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        .and()
        .passwordCompare()
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
         
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }

    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/images/**");    //.anyRequest("/images/**");
        super.configure(web);
    }
}
```

I tried other tutorials for ldap authentication and failed to implement VaadinWebSecurity. Does anybody know a correct way how to set up a VaadinWebSecurity with ldap authentication?

Above example includes working ldap authentication but after inserting user&pass, i'm redirected to login page. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not really related to Vaadin. Any Spring (Boot) Security Tutorial about LDAP Integration should get you a working solution.

Comment: Above code looks like the vaadin example (like no attempt for LDAP was
made at all).  Please add the code you have tried **to make LDAP work**
so we can improve on it.

Comment: Try code from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74196746/vaadin-flow-how-to-add-azure-active-directory-login-function/74203052#74203052](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74196746/vaadin-flow-how-to-add-azure-active-directory-login-function/74203052#74203052)

Comment: Please checkout https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/ldap.html